# Why are Ubuntu Mono letters so small?

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-font-family

I like Ubuntu Mono for coding, but one thing about the font puzzles me. Almost every editor I use it in, I have to set the size of Ubuntu Mono two points higher than other fonts to make the letters have the same size.

What about Ubuntu Mono does this?

Is is a bug that should be addressed?

#### Example comparison from PyCharm

DejaVu Sans Mono:
[image: DejaVu Sans Mono]

Ubuntu Mono:
[image: Ubuntu Mono]

Comment: +1 Confirmed in Sublime Text Editor. Comparison between Monaco and Ubuntu Mono.

Comment: Same here, but this should be reported as a bug.

Comment: I experience the same but don't see it as an issue that annoys me. I agree that this would be better as a bug report, if it *bugs* you enough. As such it's off topic on AU.

Comment: It bugs me because it makes it hard to set something, e.g. a web page or a program showing code, in the font, and have a fallback font with same size setting.

Comment: Reported upstream https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family/+bug/1860251, please vote.